# An inequality involving critical Sobolev exponent

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

This is related to my previous question [An inequality involving Sobolev embedding with epsilon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341814/an-inequality-involving-sobolev-embedding-with-epsilon). There I wished to get that,  for given a nice bounded domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists C_\epsilon$ s.t.
$$
\|u\|_{2^*}\leq \epsilon \|\nabla u\|_2+C_\epsilon \|u\|_2, \quad \forall u\in H^1(\Omega),   
$$
where $2^*=2n/(n-2)$ is the critical Sobolev exponent. Due to the lack of compact embedding from $H^1$ into $L^{2^*}$. The above inequality is indeed incorrect, see my previous thread. Now, I hope to get a strengthened version of it: given $p\in (2,2(n+2)/n)$ (or $p\in(2,2^*)$ in the worst case), $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists C_\epsilon$ s.t.
$$
\|u\|_{2^*}\leq \epsilon (\|\nabla u\|_2+\|u\|_p^{\frac{p}{2}})+C_\epsilon(1+ \|u\|_2), \quad \forall u\in H^1(\Omega).   \tag{MCIS}
$$
I tried the example listed in [MathOverflow: Counterexample Showing The Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem Is Sharp](https://mathoverflow.net/q/81034), which does not give a counterexample. Also, arguing by contradiction seems not to work. Any help is greatly acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

The $1$ in parentheses is useless; it doesn't scale if you multiply $u$ by a constant. So your inequality can hold for all $u\in  H^1$ if and only if 
$$\|u\|_{2^*}\leq \epsilon (\|\nabla u\|_2+\|u\|_p^{\frac{p}{2}})+C_\epsilon \|u\|_2$$
holds. And here the scaling of the variable $u_t = u^{n/2^*}u(tx)$ becomes an issue: namely, $\|u_t\|_{2^*}$ and $\|\nabla u_t\|_2$ are constant, while $\|u_t\|_p\to 0$ for all $p< 2^*$.

So, you don't get this for $p<2^*$. (And for  $p\ge 2^*$, the inequality follows just from Hölder's inequality).

Comment: Thank you @1999. The inequality is incorrect, and has been answered in [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210446/an-inequality-with-critical-sobolev-exponent]

Comment: So you are posting in two places and wait where you get an answer first? Your choice. But this is the last time I answered your question.